# Safari Web Extension Sign in With Google

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, safari-web-extension

Safari now can use web extensions.

But `browser.identity` or `chrome.identity` is not supported. So `launchWebAuthFlow` is not working.

In the docs they just say.

> identity Not supported. Initiate an OAuth flow in a new tab.

How can I do it? Is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

It currently seems not possible to implement a OAuth flow in a safari web extension.

There's an Apple Developer thread with a workaround involving redirecting to a random URL and intercepting this in `webRequest.onBeforeRedirect`, but it appears to be broken as of Safari 15.4: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/670165

2021:

> As a workaround, you may use whatever reachable URL as an OAuth redirect URL and use `webRequest.onBeforeRedirect` to capture the redirect attempt and 'force redirect' e.g. by tabs.update.

2023:

> The `webRequest` API is not available from non-persistent background pages (or service workers) and v3 forbids persistent background pages. The `declarativeNetRequest` allows redirecting to a path in your extension, but via this route the original request is not available. A workaround for this is to redirect using a regexSubstitution. This works fine in Chrome, but not in Safari, because redirects to safari-web-extension:// are blocked.

The OP has created a webkit bug report you may find useful: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=256054

> Error: Redirection to URL with a scheme that is not HTTP(S)